# meteor resetpassword is not working

Tags: meteor, passwords

i'm making custom meteor account.

referring to this url >> [Building a customized accounts ui for Meteor](http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor)

but i have problem.

```
if (Accounts._resetPasswordToken) {
   Session.set('resetPassword', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);
}
```

client side called this code is always undifined.(Accounts._resetPasswordToken)

finally i want to call

```
  Accounts.resetPassword(Session.get('resetPassword'), pw, function(err){
```

Comment: Can you post more code so we can have more context?  Have you imported Accounts into the file where this code is executed?  I verified that `_resetPasswordToken` is still correct [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/87681c8f166641c6c3e34958032a5a070aa2d11a/packages/accounts-base/url_client.js#L41)

Comment: @jordanwillis Thank you . It was a great help to me